# Read in text file then write new file with new output

Tags: perl

I'm very new to `perl`. I have a text file I want to read in and count the number of rows beginning with "6" and return the total to the previous line that began with "5" where the `###` are. At the end I want to return the total of all lines beginning with "6" on the last line that begins with "9" where the `######`. How can I go about this program.

---

**ex.txt**

```
120180117674189                                                                 
500000120180117###000000006000L                                                 
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001                    
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001                    
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001                    
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001                    
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001                    
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001                    
500000220180117###000000162420L                                                 
6CC0000458      00001019   000078600 000000000003585CNCP0001                    
6CC0000447      00001019   000005500 000000000003584CNCP0001                    
6CC0000483      00001005   000001800 000000000003588CNCH0001                    
6CC0000488      00001005   000023800 000000000003589CNCP0001                    
6CC0000446      00001005   000052720 000000000003583CNCP0001                    
500000320180117###000000429631L                                                 
61234           00001017   000085831 000000000123456   12345                    
6123            00001017   000000000 000000000012345    1234                    
612             00001003   000343800 000000000001234     123                    
9      ######000000592051
```

**Wex.txt** (should output)

```
120180117674189                                                                 
500000120180117006000000006000L                                                 
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001                    
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001                    
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001                    
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001                    
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001                    
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001                    
500000220180117005000000162420L                                                 
6CC0000458      00001019   000078600 000000000003585CNCP0001                    
6CC0000447      00001019   000005500 000000000003584CNCP0001                    
6CC0000483      00001005   000001800 000000000003588CNCH0001                    
6CC0000488      00001005   000023800 000000000003589CNCP0001                    
6CC0000446      00001005   000052720 000000000003583CNCP0001                    
500000320180117003000000429631L                                                 
61234           00001017   000085831 000000000123456   12345                    
6123            00001017   000000000 000000000012345    1234                    
612             00001003   000343800 000000000001234     123                    
9      000014000000592051
```

New file

120180117674189
500000120180117006000000006000L
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001
6CC0000490      00001013   000001000 000000000003590CNCP0001
6CC0000491      00001007   000001000 000000000003591CNCP0001
6CC0000493      00001002   000001000 000000000003592CNCP0001
500000220180117###000000162420L
6CC0000458      00001019   000078600 000000000003585CNCP0001
6CC0000447      00001019   000005500 000000000003584CNCP0001
6CC0000483      00001005   000001800 000000000003588CNCH0001
6CC0000488      00001005   000023800 000000000003589CNCP0001
6CC0000446      00001005   000052720 000000000003583CNCP0001
500000320180117###000000429631L
61234           00001017   000085831 000000000123456   12345
6123            00001017   000000000 000000000012345    1234
612             00001003   000343800 000000000001234     123
9      ######000000592051

Comment: Can you show us your code, what you've tried in order to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $fn = 'ex.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my @lines;
my @count;
my $cur_count = undef; # undef --> before first line starting with 6
my $flag = 2;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    push @lines, $line;
    if ( $line =~ /^6/) {
        $cur_count = 0 if !defined $cur_count;
        $flag = 2 if $flag == 1;
        $cur_count++;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^5/ ) {
        push @count, $cur_count if (defined $cur_count) && $flag == 2;
        $cur_count = 0;
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        $flag = 2 if $flag == 1;
    }
}
push @count, $cur_count if defined $cur_count;
close $fh;

my $total = sum @count;

my $j = 0;
for (@lines) {
    if (/^(5[^#]*)[#]+(.*)$/) {
        say $1, (sprintf "%06d", $count[$j++]), $2;
    }
    elsif (/^(9[^#]*)[#]+(.*)$/) {
        say $1, (sprintf "%06d", $total), $2;
    }
    else {
        say;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To write to a file from within the script:

```
# [...]
my $savefn = 'output.txt';
open ( my $sfh, '>', $savefn ) or die "Could not open file '$savefn': $!";
my $j = 0;
for (@lines) {
    if (/^(5[^#]*)[#]+(.*)$/) {
        say $sfh $1, (sprintf "%06d", $count[$j++]), $2;
    }
    elsif (/^(9[^#]*)[#]+(.*)$/) {
        say $sfh $1, (sprintf "%06d", $total), $2;
    }
    else {
        say $sfh $_;
    }
}
close $sfh;
```

Comment: How would I write the output to another file ?

Comment: The simplest way would be just pipe it: `perl script.pl > output.txt`

Comment: Is there a way to add in the write file to the code instead of doing it from the command line

Comment: Say for I say for instance one of the 5 lines didn’t have ### but had number 006 already there would the count still count correctly  or would I have to add an or to the elsif statement

Comment: @Trey This would be a good test case to add to your test suite. If you haven't written one yet, this is a good time to start!

Comment: @Trey If you change this line: `500000120180117###000000006000L` to this: `500000120180117000000006000L`, for example it will not know where to insert the count. Previously it knew that it should insert the count after `###` but now, what should it use to determine where to insert (when there are no `#`s)?